# Python SQLite3: Select from table by multiple keys and list of key values, using parametrization if possible

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

If I query SqLite table using single key, I can use the following code for parametrization:

```
contact_phones_list = ['+123456789', '+987654321']
q = "select * from {} WHERE user_phone in ({})".format(
                      my_table_name, 
                      ', '.join('?' for _ in contact_phones_list)
                      )

res = self.cursor.execute(q, contact_phones_list).fetchall()
```

Now I want to query for key pairs for which I have values:

```
keys = ['user_phone', 'contact_phone']
values = [('+1234567', '+1000000'), ('+987654321', '+1200000')]
q = "select contact_phone, is_main, aliases from {} WHERE ({}) in ({})".format( 
                 my_table_name, 
                 ', '.join(keys), 
                 ', '.join('(?, ?)' for _ in values)
                 )

res = self.cursor.execute(q, values).fetchall()
```

I'm getting error "row value misused". I tried many combinations with sublist instead of tuple, single "?", etc.

How can I create parametrization in this case?

EDIT: adding "VALUES" keyword and flattening list works:

```
keys = ['user_phone', 'contact_phone']
values = [('+1234567', '+1000000'), ('+987654321', '+1200000')]
values_q = []
for v in values:
    values_q += [v[0], v[1]]

q = "select * from my_table_name WHERE ({}) IN (VALUES {})".format(
    ', '.join(keys), 
    ', '.join('(?, ?)' for _ in values)
    )
res = cursor.execute(q, values_q).fetchall()
```

Is this a workaround or only acceptable solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/rowvalue.html):

> For a row-value IN operator, the left-hand side (hereafter "LHS") can be either a parenthesized list of values or a subquery with multiple columns. But the right-hand side (hereafter "RHS") must be a subquery expression.

You're building up something that looks like `(?,?) IN ((?,?), (?,?))`, which doesn't meet that requirement. The syntax `(?,?) IN (VALUES (?,?), (?,?))` works, though.

Also, I think you might have to flatten out that list of tuples you pass to the prepared statement, but somebody more knowledgeable about python would have to say for sure.

Comment: Actually, the following workaround seem to work:  `select * from my_table where (user_phone, contact_phone)  in (VALUES (?,?), (?,?))`. To fill up the placeholders I create list where I just concatenate values like `values_q = ['+1234567', '+1000000', '+987654321', '+1200000']`

Comment: I just don't know which parts of SQL statement are being filled by library